# React-native Log in with Facebook App refreshes app

Tags: facebook, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I am using react-native-fbsdk and am on IOS. When users log in with Facebook their are two buttons they can press. **Log in with the Facebook App** or **Log in with Phone Number or Email Address**. Logging in with the Phone Number or email address works perfectly, I get the user object and create a user account for them. But when users press **Log in with the Facebook App** I don't get sent a user object, and the whole app refreshes where they get pushed to the log in page and the Facebook button has turned to **Log out**. I am not too sure on how to approach this as when users log in with the Facebook App none of my console.logs or alerts are getting called and the whole app just refreshes. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
           <LoginButton
            readPermissions={["email","public_profile"]}
            onLoginFinished={
              (error, result) => {
                console.log("onLoginFinished: ", result);
                if (error) {
                  console.log("login has error: ", result.error);
                } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                  console.log("login is cancelled.");
                } else {
                  AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
                    (data) => {
                      let accessToken = data.accessToken
                      console.log("accessToken.toString(): ", accessToken.toString())

                      const responseInfoCallback = (error, result) => {
                        if (error) {
                          console.log('Error fetching data: ', error)
                          //lert('Error fetching data: ' + error.toString());
                        } else {
                          console.log("responseInfoCallback:", result)
                          this.state.fbobj = result;
                          this.sendAjax();
                          //alert('Success fetching data: ' + result.toString());
                        }
                      }

                      const infoRequest = new GraphRequest(
                        '/me',
                        {
                          accessToken: accessToken,
                          parameters: {
                            fields: {
                              string: 'email,name'
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        responseInfoCallback
                      );

                      // Start the graph request.
                      new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(infoRequest).start()

                    }
                  )
                }
              }
            }
            onLogoutFinished={() => console.log("Logout")}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your button action, you will need something like this:

```
import { LoginManager, AccessToken } from 'react-native-fbsdk'

handlePressFacebookLogin = () => {
    LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile', 'email']).then(
      (result) => {
        if (!result.isCancelled) {
          AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then((data) => {
            console.log(data)
          })
        }
      }
    )
  }
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply, I've added my code just above, and I'm assuming my code is wrong because I don't have the LoginManager?

Comment: Can you make a test with the code from the Github documentation? 

https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk

Comment: In the Usage, where it says Login Button + Access Token, just copy the code inside LoginButton and test what happens

Comment: The page is still just refreshing sadly

Comment: For Android it seems to work, but not for IOS I believe, I'll double check my appdelegate.m code

Comment: Make a double check step by step in this guide: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/

Comment: After just having the basic Login code from the tutorial, and adding some appdelegate code I've noticed that I am getting a**Socket hang up** error, and a **websocket handshake error**

Comment: This just really isn't making sense to me as to why this doesn't work. Do you know how I could get rid of the log in with facebook app button by any chance?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158103/discussion-between-lucas-z-and-kcuhcx2).